# question regarding automatically generated html code while displaying files and folders

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to scan a generated "index of" html site that displays all the files and folders?

For example if I enter a local web server address in a web browser i get the following generated html site

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /component_test/TEST/ndpgsn_5_0</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /component_test/TEST/ndpgsn_5_0</h1>
<ul><li><a href="/component_test/TEST/"> Parent Directory</a></li>
<li><a href="CXS101289_LLVGREY_ATM452_2_06_P16A01_101209134111/"> CXS101289_LLVGREY_ATM452_2_06_P16A01_101209134111/</a></li>
<li><a href="CXS101289_LLVGREY_ATM452_2_06_P16A01_101213085154/"> CXS101289_LLVGREY_ATM452_2_06_P16A01_101213085154/</a></li>
<li><a href="CXS101289_LLVGREY_ATM452_2_06_P16A01_110111180811/"> CXS101289_LLVGREY_ATM452_2_06_P16A01_110111180811/</a></li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

can I access this generated html site, so that if I push a link, that a script is automatically runned, is this possible and how would I do it?

If this is **not** possible, can i make a script that scans the current file level what files that are there and then write them out so that the result will be the above code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, you need to use your own script. Depending on what server-side scripting you use, you should try to find an existing application fullfilling your expectations. E.g. http://filenice.com/demo/

Comment: So I cant get access to this temoral generated html file in any way? The thing I want to do is, if I have pushed a link in the above generated html site, are there any similar links on that html site, then write them out again. I can use these fancy filenice program, although it was nice looking =)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an Apache and that you have access to the server-settings:

You can create a file that will be appended to the generated index-page, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#readmename

Using such a file it should be possible to add a javascript of your own that is doing what you want to(guess you like to request the files via ajax if you click on a link)